# Get quote price from CoinMarketCap API in EUR instead of USD - GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cryptocurrency, google-apps-script-api, coinmarketcap

the following code works ok for me in GAS (Google Apps Script) for CoinMarketCap API

```
function cmcQuotes2() {
  
  var ss       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet    = ss.getSheetByName('base');
  var lastRow  = sheet.getLastRow();
  var extension= lastRow - 2;
  
  var oldAsset=sheet.getRange(2, 1, extension).getValues();
  var rows=[];
  var j;
  for (j=0; j < oldAsset.length; j++) {
    rows.push(oldAsset[j][0]);}
  
  var apiKey = '*** your api key'; 
  var params = {
    'method'  : 'GET',
    'qs'      : {'start': '1', 'limit': '100', 'convert': 'USD'},
    'headers' : {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true};
  
  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";

var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var data = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
  var data = data.data; 
  
  
  var i;
  for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

var asset       = data[i].symbol;               
  var quote       = data[i].quote.USD.price;
    if (quote < 1) {var a = parseFloat(quote);   var a = a.toFixed(8);   var quote = parseFloat(a);} 
    if (quote >=1) {var a = parseFloat(quote);   var a = a.toFixed(2);   var quote = parseFloat(a);} 
    
  var row=rows.indexOf(asset)+2;   

if (row>=2){
       sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(quote);
  }  
  }
}
```

**but**

no matter what I try to get the price quoted in EUR instead of USD, I can't.

I simply can't.

*convert* EUR instead of USD? Doesn't work.

```
  var params = {
    'method'  : 'GET',
    'qs'      : {'start': '1', 'limit': '100', 'convert': 'EUR'},
    'headers' : {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true};
```

*quote.EUR* instead of *quote.USD* ?? Doesn't work ..

```
var quote       = data[i].quote.EUR.price;
```

first case simply ignores EUR, second case it returns:

```
12:59:50
Errore
TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
```

What's your take about it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At `params` of `UrlFethApp.fetch(url, params)`, the property of `qs` is not existing. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- From the official document of "[Listings Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)", it seems that the value of `qs` is required to be used as the query parameters.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
  var apiKey = '*** your api key'; 
  var params = {
    'method'  : 'GET',
    'qs'      : {'start': '1', 'limit': '100', 'convert': 'USD'},
    'headers' : {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true};
  
  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";

var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

To:

```
var apiKey = '*** your api key';
var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=100&convert=USD";
var params = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'headers': {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey, 'Accept': 'application/json'},
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your API key can be used for the API you want to use. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Listings Latest (official document)](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: thanks @Tanaike, this worked for me. I hope I can ask additional info for some details in case I don't understand while working on it, but for the time being it worked and I thank you for this.

Comment: @John Galassi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.